# Can't access attribute of Angular Promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, scope, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to write a JS function using Angular such that I can have it return a value, then set a variable on the scope equal to that value. I return a promise object that according to the chrome console has an attribute with my data in it, but when I try to access that, it says it is undefined.

**Code:**

```
   function getData($scope, $http) { //line 71
    output = $http.get('/static/json/tickets').
        success(function(data, status) {
            output.data = data;
            console.log(output.data); //Within the proper scope; displays the data array
            output.status = status;
        }).
        error(function (data, status){
            output.data = data || "Error";
            output.status = status;
        });
        console.log(output); //displays the promise object, with attribute data
        console.log(output.data); // displays 'undefined' (out of scope?)
        return output


    out = getData($scope, $http);
    console.log(out); // Displays the promise object, with attribute data
    console.log(out.data); // displays 'undefined'
    $scope.data = out.data;
```

**Chrome console:**

[image: Console.log statements]

Is there any way I can put a return statement inside the `.success(data, status)` function that will make the parent function (`getData`) return that value? I'm fairly new to JS, and while I know that it's possible to return from a nested function, `.success` is a method of the promise returned by `$http.get`, and trying to return `output.data` gives an undefined object. This code:

```
function getData($scope, $http) {
dataout = {};
output = $http.get('/static/json/tickets').
    success(function(data, status) {
        dataout = data;
        console.log(output.data); //Within the proper scope; displays the data array
        output.status = status;
    }).
    error(function (data, status){
        output.data = data || "Error";
        output.status = status;
    });
    console.log(output); //displays the promise object, with attribute data
    console.log(output.data); // displays 'undefined' (out of scope?)
    return dataout
```

returns an undefined object as well, which makes me think that Angular is doing something with async that I'm not handling properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not how you use promises. The `output` variable get actually logged before the data is there. But the chrome console shows the object in its current data state.

try to log `out.data.toString()` it will log "undefined".

Try this:

```
function getData($http) {
 return $http.get('/static/json/tickets').
    success(function(data, status) {
        console.log(data); //Within the proper scope; displays the data array
        return data;
    }).
    error(function (data, status){
        return status;
    });
}
```

The `$http` will return a promise in which you attach the `success` and `error` callback and by returning a value within these callbacks, angular will wrap a promise around and return it.

And then call it like this:

```
getData($http).then(function(data){
  console.log(data);
});
```

Maybe move the method into a service and dont pass the `$http` as a parameter there.

Comment: That works, thanks. It was the callbacks that were giving me trouble.

Answer (score 2):

You need to let the promise resolve before you can get the data.  Here is an example using a factory and controller:

```
app.factory('Tickets',function($http,$q) {
    var dataout = $q.defer();

    $http.get('/static/json/tickets/').success(function(data,status) {
            dataout.resolve(data);
    });

    return {
        getData: function() {
            return dataout.promise;
        }
    }
});

app.controller('GetData',function($scope,Tickets) {
    Tickets.getData().then(function(data) {
        $scope.out = data;
    });
});
```